# Where can I find the fingerprint of 'bazaar.launchpad.net'?

Tags: ssh, launchpad, bazaar

I'd like to verify the RSA key fingerprint I'm shown, where would I find it online*? Please don't post random pages showing that fingerprint, it should be an official one.

*) I know that's not the best way to verify it, but it's better than just blindly typing 'yes'. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bug #238869 in Launchpad itself](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/238869) indicates that there is currently no secure method for verifying Launchpad's SSH host key fingerprint.

Comment: This looks pretty abandoned, but I got a similar response on #launchpad.